# Using colcon test --pytest-with-coverage on a CMake-based package with both Python & C++ source files

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to generate code coverage reports. I'm running these commands in a workspace that has all repos from the `master` `ros2.repos` :

```
$ colcon build --packages-up-to ros2trace tracetools tracetools_launch tracetools_read tracetools_test tracetools_trace --cmake-args --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DINSTALL_EXAMPLES=OFF -DSECURITY=ON --ament-cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --coverage" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --coverage"
$ colcon test --packages-select ros2trace tracetools tracetools_launch tracetools_read tracetools_test tracetools_trace --pytest-with-coverage --event-handlers console_direct+ --executor sequential
```

I based the above commands on the `nightly_linux_coverage` job's `colcon build` and `colcon test` commands ([build](https://ci.ros2.org/view/nightly/job/nightly_linux_coverage/793/consoleFull#console-section-14) and [test](https://ci.ros2.org/view/nightly/job/nightly_linux_coverage/793/consoleFull#console-section-598)), although I removed the explicit `-DBUILD_TESTING=ON` because one package failed (it shouldn't change anything for the packages I do want to check).

For pure Python packages (i.e. those with `setup.py` files), everything works. I get `coverage.xml`/`coverage.html`/etc. files in the package's build directory (`build/$PACKAGE_NAME/`). However, for C++ packages (using CMake) that also have Python files, I get `gcov` reports, but I do not get any `coverage.xml`/`coverage.html`/etc. files.

How can I do this? Maybe I'm missing something. There unfortunately does not seem to be any tutorial that covers *everything* for generating code coverage reports with `colcon`.

I'm using `colcon-core` 0.5.5, which does have the `--pytest-with-coverage` option so that the package doesn't need to explicitly declare a test dependency on `pytest-cov` in its `setup.py`, because, well, it's a CMake package, not a Python package. https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/commit/adf1681c58c57762f7e8d3eb92097d6471e3eec3#diff-98c77177c236ee6e1b0446c20944c428

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346767/using-colcon-test---pytest-with-coverage-on-a-cmake-based-package-with-both-python-&-c++-source-files/) by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2020-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-03-15**:
The option `--pytest-with-coverage` only affects Python packages (see `colcon test --help` and in which group the option is described).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-03-15**:
How are you invoking the test in CMake? If you e.g. use `ament_add_pytest_test` that function doesn't have an option to enable coverage atm. It should be fairly easy to add such an option though.

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2020-03-15**:
oh right, I totally overlooked "Arguments for 'python' packages."

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2020-03-15**:
I'll look into adding it then.

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2020-03-15**:
I am indeed using `ament_add_pytest_test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As noted in the comments above, it wasn't possible.

However, as of [ament_cmake#226](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/pull/226), one can enable coverage with `pytest_cov` for tests added with `ament_add_pytest_test` using the `AMENT_CMAKE_PYTEST_WITH_COVERAGE` option, or it can be enabled by default for a package by declaring a `<test_depend>` on `python3-pytest-cov`.

Also, as of [colcon-mixin-repository#23](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-mixin-repository/pull/23), there is a `coverage-pytest` mixin (for `build`) that sets that option to `ON`.

---

Originally posted by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) with karma: 641 on 2020-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0